# CTRL-F Opens Terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have somehow set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open xterm Terminal (not my default).

I tried finding the configuration in dconf, but I didn't find anything mentioning keyboard shortcuts, except one custom column with "command1" to some number, but it didn't have anything with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

How do I change back?

Comment: Go to System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and find it there.

Comment: Have you got `xbindkeys` installed, as ctrl + f is one of the defaults enabled in `~/.xbindkeysrc` that can conflict with your other keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Mik I'd add that as an answer :-)

Comment: @Seth Done. This is the most likely cause I should think, considering it is specifically the ctrl+f shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have `xbindkeys` installed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is one of the default shortcuts enabled that launches `xterm`. It can, however, conflict with your other custom keyboard shortcuts.

To deactivate the shortcut, edit your `~/.xbindkeysrc` and comment out the shortcut so it looks like this:

```
# set directly keycode (here control + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  c:41 + m:0x4
```

Now, this setting will not be read until `xbindkeys` restarts, so run `killall xbindkeys` and then `xbindkeys &` if you want to restart it. Alternatively, you can just logout and login again.

Comment: YES! It bugged me for days! I installed xbindkeys to help someone here and totally forgot about it. Thank you VERY much.